# Will I run into a problem if I use an 18AWG extension cable for 240V device?

Tags: gauge, awg

I currently have a length of SOOW 18AWG with ground connected to my breaker box.

One lead is connected to phase 1 on a 15A breaker.  One lead is connected to phase 2 on a 15A breaker.  ...3 is ground/common.  The breakers are tied together so they both trip if one trips.

With this, I now have a standard 110V style extension cord that is delivering 240V.

This cord's purpose is to fire up two Martin MAC 500 stage lights in a temporary setting.  The lights are rated at 3.4A each at 240V.  18AWG SOOW is rated at 600V & 10A.

The distance from the breaker box for these lights will be approximately 100'.

Is 18AWG sufficient, or do I need to increase to 14AWG?

Comment: SOOW 18AWG is rated at 7 amps at over 50'. I would prefer to go up a thickness. What concerns me is your statement "With this, I now have a standard 110V style extension cord that is delivering 240V." doing this is an accident waiting to happen sometime in the future someone is going to plug a 110V load into this.

Comment: 18AWG is 6.385 Ohms per 1000ft. 100 foot run, both ways is 200 feet. That's 1.3 Ohms. At 3.4A x2, that is a voltage drop of 9V which is 3.68% of 240V and could be considered tolerable. As far as voltage drop due to long length goes.

Comment: Fully aware of the risk of it being identified as a 110V outlet.  It's a temporary one time gig and won't be up for more than a few hours.

Comment: fun fact: Actual wires don't care about voltage, but they care about amperage. Insulation cares about voltage and heat, but doesn't care about amps.

Comment: I would not use a 120V socket for 240V no matter how brief the use is. If that is what you mean by a "110V style extension cord" NO NO NO, Don't Do It!!! Put the proper socket on the end of that cord. I would also be concerned about 18 AWG stranded wire connected directly to a circuit breaker. That may not be a proper and secure connection.

Comment: That's a good point ... stranded wire connected to a circuit breaker seems like a bad idea regardless of whether or not it would work.  The challenge is that the actual fixtures that are configured for 240V have regular plugs attached to them.  I will probably need to wire up appropriate connections.